# ¿Por qué mi aplicación .jar ya no funciona?

Tags: java, netbeans, biometrico

Tengo una aplicación *.jar* funcionando perfectamente en otro pc y me puse a hacerle cambios, como por ejemplo quitarle el botón para optimizar tiempo. Pero resultó que mi aplicación .jar ya no funciona. Es decir, la que tenia en el otro pc. ¿Qué pudo haber pasado? Me sale el siguiente error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: En ese stacktrace te dice en qué clase y en qué linea se origina ese error, para que te podamos ayudar necesitas compartirnos ese código.

Comment: Si funciona --> No se toca.

Comment: Si funcionaba antes de los cambios y falla después, obviamente el cambio que has hecho no es correcto. Con la información que nos facilitas, esta es toda la respuesta que se te puede dar.

Comment: pero entonces la conclusión es que la aplicación que tengo en otro equipo si la modifico desde el mio se puede cambiar, no se supone que cuando uno genera el .jar es una "versión" aparte de la que estoy cambiando?
otra cosa esto que significa o para que se necesita... ----[serial] serializable class IngresoHuella has no definition of serialVersionUID----
de ante mano agradezco sus respuesta muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que te estás liando muchísimo, la otra aplicación que usaba el "jar.1.0" funcionaba correctamente, después creas otro .jar "1.1" y ya deja de funcionar porque has tocado algo. Si ahora el jar.1.0 también deja de funcionar, puede deberse por ejemplo a que hayas modificado algo en la base de datos o algo externo. El error que estás poniendo, puede ser por muchos motivos, aunque me aventuro a decir que viene porque no estás generando una ID nueva (o incremental) para el nuevo registro en la tabla.